# printf doesn't work in ndk android libc

Tags: c, android-ndk, shared-libraries, libc

I've built shared library for aarch64 via android ndk. 
In the source code I just write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

I have written dynamic loader for my aarch64 on x86 emulator and try to call printf from dlopened library from /platrorm/x86_64/libc.so
passed parameters as described in abi.
But it doesn't print anything. 
I've run code in gdb and for printf call I get this:

```
0x000000000041f5e4  822     __asm__ volatile("call *%0":"=r"(call_ptr):"r (call_ptr));  
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x41f5e4 <native_call_a64+245>:  callq  *%rax
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7fce4c4 in malloc () from /home/sabramov/test2/ndklib64//libc.so
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7fce4c4 <malloc>: push   %rbp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7fce4c5 in malloc () from /home/sabramov/test2/ndklib64//libc.so
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7fce4c5 <malloc+1>:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7fce4c8 in malloc () from /home/sabramov/test2/ndklib64//libc.so
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7fce4c8 <malloc+4>:   pop    %rbp
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7fce4c9 in malloc () from /home/sabramov/test2/ndklib64//libc.so
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7fce4c9 <malloc+5>:   retq
```

But the same code works when I get shared libs from /lib/x86_64_gnu.
Printf works well for host libs but printf was found in libdl.so, not in libc.so

And I need to use ndk/platform libs in my project but not host libs.

Can anybody help me and say why printf just return from ndk libc.so ?
(other libc functions like malloc don't work too).

Comment: [By default, the Android system sends `stdout` and `stderr` output to `/dev/null`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#viewingStd)

Comment: But what about malloc and other libc function ? It has the same gdb dump as printf.